# Classes functions that need access to database

Tags: php, function, class, pdo

I don't know what to search for regarding my question, so hopefully someone can help me.

What's the most efficient and shortest method of setting up a database connection class and several other classes with functions that need access to database without repeating myself?

Would there be a way to declare a variable such as $pdo that can be access from any classes?

Or, if someone can tell me the right terminology to serach for, that would be  be helpful.

Thank you.

For example:

```
class connection {
    PDO data connection goes here
}

class A {
    function foo() {
        //This function needs access to database
        $pdo->query($query);
    }
}

class B {
    function bar() {
        //Also needs access to database
        $pdo->query($query)
    }
}
```

Comment: Search for MVC (Model View Controller).

Answer (score 0):

I would create database class and extend it to other classes:

```
class connection {
    PDO data connection goes here
}
```

and class A like this,

```
class A extends connection{
    function foo() {
        //This function needs access to database
        $pdo->query($query);
    }
}
```

Now `class A` can access `class connection` methods and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you could create a class to connect to database

```
class dbConnect {
//Connection goes here
}
```

then create a base model class extending this connection class also you could do so in the constructor function so as soon as the class is instantiated connection is set

```
class BaseModel extends dbConnect {
}
```

then autoload both classes every time your app runs using php's autoload ref:

```
php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php
```

and then extend other classes as per need

class xyz extends BaseModel {
}